# Make dynamically created AttributeDefImpl read only after it is populated

Tags: java, jsf, oracle-adf

I am new to using the ADF framework. I am dynamically creating view objects that appear on a JSF front-end page. I want to create a dynamic view on the front end that cannot be edited once it is populated and rendered. My code is as follows:

```
    AttributeDefImpl dynamicViewAttribute = dynamicViewDef.addViewAttribute(name, alias, javaType);
    dynamicViewAttribute.setUpdateableFlag(AttributeDef.READONLY);
```

This fails as once the view object is set to READONLY, it cannot be updated. If I change the line of code as follows:

```
dynamicViewAttribute.setUpdateableFlag(AttributeDef.UPDATEABLE);
```

There is no error and the page displays correctly, but the user can edit/update the text in the view object.

How can I accomplish what I need i.e. display the view object text without letting the user edit/update it? Remember this has to be dynamically created so I cannot set readOnly=true on the jsf.

Answer (score 1):

If this will be dynamically determined  , then you can send your flag or Attribute i.e ("**IsReadOnlyFlag**") in the ViewObject.

in your jsf page change the attribute **readOnly** for 
 the inputText  to **readOnly**=#{bindings.**IsReadOnlyFlag**.inputValue eq 'Y'}

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot do this as there is no element in the jsf page. This view attribute is created in java with the code as shown in my question.